# Some colors don't work in JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, colors, hex, rgb

So the title is a bit vague. For users that are Rank "Administrator" they have a color code of HEX: #660000. Mods: #70DB70. Users: #000000. None of these colors appear in the text area. At first I thought maybe the code isn't going through but it is, here is the message being received from the server:

```
{"type":"SEND_MESSAGE","sender":"HalloTast","message":"ee","color":"#660000"}
```

and just appears as this

[image]

Then I thought maybe it didn't work because it was a HEX color so I looked it up and curtsey of another question, I found this:

```
    public static Color hex2Rgb(String colorStr) {
    return new Color(
            Integer.valueOf( colorStr.substring( 1, 3 ), 16 ),
            Integer.valueOf( colorStr.substring( 3, 5 ), 16 ),
            Integer.valueOf( colorStr.substring( 5, 7 ), 16 ) );
}
```

then I would assign that as the color. Still didn't work. Just black like in the previous screenshot. So I tried just putting in Color.RED when it was needed on the client end and it worked like so:

[image]

Comment: what in your first snap shot color is not black .it's write color for `#660000`

Answer (score 0):

You can set Hex values in `Color` class constructor itself which accept Hex values something like:

```
jTextPane.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0xff0096));//Some pinkish color
```

[image]